# Why visual studio shows UML Use Case diagram Association Shape as Arrow? Is it correct?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uml, diagram, use-case

I am making a UML Use Case Diagram for the college project. I saw many diagram in which the association is shown simply by a **line**. I read few question/answers & articles about it, they also said to use line.

I am using Visual Studio to create the diagram. But the association in visual studio shows the arrow on the diagram. So my question is that, the created diagram is correct or wrong? Why Visual Studio shows arrow? Tried to use simple Line shape but no luck it doesn't drop on actor.

I want to know what is correct with arrow? or without arrow? or both are correct?
See in the image it is showing Arrow.

[image]

Comment: Use case associations can optionally show direction, indicating who starts the interaction.  I do not have VS 2013, but you could try right-clicking the association and see if you can turn on/off directionality.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012, right clicking doesn't show the menu you said or similar.

Comment: I used directed associations for the primary and undirected ones for secondary actors. So that picture is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked notation used in

- [UML Superstructure 2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF/)
- [UML Specification 2.5 Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/)
- [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor-association.html)
- [Visual Studio 2013 online help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409427.aspx)
- [Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/standard_uml_models/usecase.html) tool

Although none of the documents explicitly bans using an arrow, and some pseudo-UML drawing tools allow you to connect elements using pink line with pig tail, all of the above resources use as standard the **without arrow** notation. It would be wise to follow them.

You can turn-off the navigability of the default association (and make the arrow disappear) like this:

[image]

The screenshot was taken using "Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 CTP". I believe that the user interface principles would be very similar also in your Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @ThomasKilian I don't see the reason why using the association's navigability would be a good idea for primary actor and not good for secondary actors. Can you provide some resource recommending it other then _its nice_?

Comment: The resource is simply my practical experience and since UML lets the speaker quite some freedom, I adopted this idiom. The arrow makes clear that the primary actor triggers the UC while the undirected shows that the secondary is only involved.